# Selecting two sets of conditions in awk

Tags: awk

I have a table

```
1 1
1 0
0 1
0 0
```

I want to print the lines with two sets of selection criteria separated by **OR**.

Criteria set 1 : (Column 1 >= 1 and Column 2 = 0)

**OR**

Criteria set 2 : (Column 1 = 0 and Column 2 >= 1)

Expected output is

```
1 0
0 1
```

I have written something like this but didn't work

```
awk '($1>=1 && $2=0)||($1=0 && $2>=1) {print $0}'
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Use `==` for comparison, not `=` which is for assignment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an assignment operator (`=`) rather than a test of equality (`==`). The boolean result of assigning zero to something is "false". This is why the test never succeeds.

---

The idiomatic `awk` command would be

```
awk '($1 >= 1 && $2 == 0) || ($1 == 0 && $ 2 >= 1)'
```

The `{ print $0 }` is not needed as this is the default action for any condition that does not have an action.

If you just want to skip lines with the same values in column one and two (gives the same output for the given data):

```
awk '$1 != $2'
```

The output in both cases is

```
1 0
0 1
```

Comment: No `awk '$1 != $2'` will print a line `1 2` or if both numbers were >0, as OP stated, one of numbers must be 0

Comment: @αғsнιη That's why I was careful to formulate the text the way I did.

Answer (score 3):

Beside of the problem you had in your `awk` command using `=` instead of `==` for comparison that [**Kusalananda**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) [pointed that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396786/72456). What I understood from your input and the command you are using, you want those line when at least one of those are zero).

Assuming you don't have negative values, then you could use:

```
awk '($1 && !$2) || (!$1 && $2)' infile
```

Or even shorter (you can use `-` as well).

```
awk '($1 * !$2) + (!$1 * $2)' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative `egrep` solution:

```
egrep '^([1-9][0-9]* *0|0 *[1-9][0-9]*)$' file
```

The output:

```
1 0
0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to use OR** between the two you can even add more criteria just add them each on a separete line save it in a textfile eg 'criteria.awk'
and run it like this : awk -f criteria.awk table.dat

here is the content of the awkscriptfile:

```
{
    if ($1 >= 1 && $2 == 0) print $0;
    if($1 == 0 && $2 >=1) print $0;
}
```